# Problem with dependencies in Angular 8 Library

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm facing some strange problem with Angular, I create a new Library for one project with 2 peerdependecies: Bootstrap and Fontawesome 5.
Bootstrap imports works like a charm, but FontAwesome does not show the proper icon in the html view.

[image: icon in view]

- Already tried to reinstall de packages in the main project
- Set the file path in the scss on the library
- Also tried to use individual imports for the icons

The library files:

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 dragdrop-area">
            <i class="fas fa-file-upload"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt fa-2x"></i>
            Drag'n'Drop area
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS(with imports):

```
@import '../../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all';
// tried to
// @import '../../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
//@import '../../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
//@import '../../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Angular.json(Project with my library)

```
"styles": [
"node_modules/fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css",
"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
"src/styles.scss"
]
```

Comment: Did you follow the instructions of https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome ?

Comment: I'm not using angular-fortawesome.

Comment: Apparently you should, per documentation.

Comment: Well, where Its said that? Its a option pack, I want to use fontawesome 5, like I already use fontawesome 4.7. Its not make sense to me, I know its more easy just install angular pack and use it, but I want to use fontawesome npm pack because I have this option too.

Comment: See https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/angular

Comment: @LppEdd Ok, thanks.